# How to test my React Component which render other one?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs, enzyme

i have to test a React component (datePicker) with Enzyme and Jest inside other component himself inside other component...
i want to check the value of a input with id: gt3ct.
my DOM looks like that : [my DOM](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ceIwH.png)

i trying somethings like this :
`expect(wrapper.find(UpDate).at(0).find('#gt3ct').at(0).props('value').value()).toBe('1745-12-01');`
but it doesn't work because UpDate himself render other component which render other one, ...
so i think
`expect(wrapper.find(UpDate).at(0).find(UpDate).at(0).find(ErrorDisplay).at(0).find(SingleDatePicker).find(OutSideClickHandler).at(0)"Other find".at(0).find('#gt3ct').at(0).props('value').value()).toBe('1745-12-01')`
but it's long to write and may be overweight for just testing one string...

Answer (score 0):

i finaly found this and it works !

```
wrapper.find("input").props().value
```

nb : there only one input so it didn't return an Collection (array or something else) but my nodeReact directly so at(x) is useless here